# Ionic2: buttons not appear

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic2 and I used this code to make two ionic buttons:

```
<ion-item>
                <button item-end ion-button id="addToCart" color="secondary">
                    Add To Cart
                </button><br/>
                <button item-end ion-button id="bottomIcon" clear icon-only>
                    <ion-icon name="md-trash"></ion-icon>
                </button><br/>
            </ion-item>
```

and the css code:

```
#bottomIcon {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    color: lightgray;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    border: 2px solid #F0F0F0;
}
#addToCart {
    width: 85px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

and this is the output:
[image: the buttons in android]
[image: the 2 buttons in ios]

anyone knows the problem? and thanks in advance

Comment: *"anyone knows the problem?"* . I don't, can you clarify? Is the first image your expected output and the second image your current output? Could you recreate this in a Plunkr?

Comment: Sooo the buttons do appear? What is the question?

Comment: @Ivaro18 The first image is the output in android device and second is the output in iOS device

Comment: @devqon it doesn't appear in iOS and it appears in android but not the expected output the output should be green button for the first button and the second button should have gray background

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code in a plunker which for some reason I can't save and it works fine. We miss some code I think

Comment: @Al-shimaaAdel how does it look in Chrome? If it looks the same like android you could debug it there.That the trash icon is alone makes sense since you have `<br />` tags, the add to cart button should be above your trash button and not next to it.

Comment: @Ivaro18 I copy and paste code in another labtop and it worked well, but from this Labtop The problem exists

Comment: <br/> isn't my problem, the buttons color doesn't work well, The output in Chrome as that in the images above

Comment: <br/> isn't my problem, the buttons color doesn't work well, The output in Chrome as that in the images above

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

on html

```
 <ion-item (click)="select($event, item)">
   <div>
    <h2>Sample</h2>  
   </div>

   <ion-icon (click)="edit($event, item)" item-right name="create" ></ion-icon>
   <ion-icon (click)="delete($event, item)" item-right name="trash"></ion-icon> 
   <ion-icon (click)="sync($event, item,i)" item-right name="sync"></ion-icon>
 </ion-item>
```

on page component

```
   select(event, item){
      //your code here
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
   edit(event, item){
      //your code here
      event.stopPropagation();
    }

   ...
   ...
```

Comment: It doesn't work and it is not my problem,, my problem is that the buttons doesn't appear as expected?